# How do I call a variable within a class?

Tags: python, class, for-loop, variables, pygame

I am trying to make a game like Geometry Dash, where the world will move to the left at a set rate, while the player remains in certain x position. In my code, once you go to the World class, you will see that I am using a piece of code that calls to a list, called world_data, to set the position of each block. But, because img_rect.x is within the class, I cannot call it in another definition in the class or within the While loop. However, this could be because it defined in a for loop?

```
# importing libraries
import pygame
from pygame import *

# Initialising pygame
pygame.init()

# Window size
width = 500
height = 500
tile_size = 25

def draw_grid():
    for line in range(0, 20):
        pygame.draw.line(screen, (0, 0, 0), (0, line * tile_size), (width, line * tile_size))
        pygame.draw.line(screen, (0, 0, 0), (line * tile_size, 0), (line * tile_size,height))
 
# Initialise game window
pygame.display.set_caption('Dashing')
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

# defining colors
black = pygame.Color(0, 0, 0)
white = pygame.Color(255, 255, 255)
red = pygame.Color(255, 0, 0)
green = pygame.Color(0, 255, 0)
blue = pygame.Color(0, 0, 255)
sb = pygame.Color(135, 206, 235)

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
  def __init__(self):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.image = pygame.Surface((25, 25))
    self.image.fill(black)
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.center = (87, height/2)
    self.width = self.image.get_width()
    self.height = self.image.get_height()

  def update(self):
    dx = 0
    dy = 0
    q = 10
    self.vel_y = 0
    
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE] and self.jumped == False:
        self.vel_y = -50
        self.jumped = True
    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE] == False:
        self.jumped = False

    self.vel_y += 1
    if self.vel_y > 10:
      self.vel_y = 10
    dy += self.vel_y
      
        #add gravity
    self.vel_y += 12
    if self.vel_y > 10:
      self.vel_y = 10
      dy += self.vel_y

    #check for collision
    for tile in world.tile_list:
      if tile[1].colliderect(self.rect.x + dx, self.rect.y, self.width - 2, self.height):
        dx = 0

          #check for collision in y direction
      if tile[1].colliderect(self.rect.x, self.rect.y + dy, self.width, self.height):
        #check if below the ground i.e. jumping
        if self.vel_y < 0:
            dy = tile[1].bottom - self.rect.top
            self.vel_y = 0
        #check if above the ground i.e. falling
        elif self.vel_y >= 0:
            dy = tile[1].top - self.rect.bottom
            self.vel_y = 0

    #update player coordinates
    self.rect.x += dx
    self.rect.y += dy

    if self.rect.bottom > height:
      self.rect.bottom = height
      dy = 0
    screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), self.rect, 2)

class World():
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.tile_list = []

    #load images
        block = pygame.image.load('middle_block.png')
        spike = pygame.image.load('spike.png')

        row_count = 0
        for row in data:
            col_count = 0
            for tile in row:
                if tile == 1:
                    img = pygame.transform.scale(block, (tile_size, tile_size))
                    img_rect = img.get_rect()
                    img_rect.x = col_count * tile_size
                    img_rect.y = row_count * tile_size
                    
                    tile = (img, img_rect)
                    self.tile_list.append(tile)
                if tile == 2:
                    img = pygame.transform.scale(spike, (tile_size, tile_size))
                    img_rect = img.get_rect()
                    img_rect.x = col_count * tile_size
                    img_rect.y = row_count * tile_size
                    tile = (img, img_rect)
                    self.tile_list.append(tile)
                col_count += 1
            row_count += 1

    def draw(self, data):
        for tile in self.tile_list:
            screen.blit(tile[0], tile[1])

world_data = [  
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
]

#fps
fps = 20
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

player = Player()
world = World(world_data)

run = True
while run == True:
  screen.fill(sb)
  draw_grid()
  world.draw(world_data)
  player.update()

  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        run = False

  pygame.display.update()
  clock.tick(fps)
pygame.quit()
```

I know this is a lot of code lol. I am not the greatest coder so please critique anything else even if you don't know the actual answer.

Comment: you are creating a new img_rect every pass through the for loop, but you are saving the reference to it within your self.tile_list.  What do you mean you can't call it from anywhere?

Comment: A function or method can be "called". A variable or an attributed cannot be "called". A variable or an attribute is accessed, read or written.

Comment: There is not just 1 `img_rect`. There are many `img_rect`s and they are stored in `world.tile_list`.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I said called, but I meant like access/change.

Answer (score 0):

Think about what declaring a variable means inside of a loop. The general purpose of a loop is to repeat an operation, well, when you declare a variable inside the loop, it's getting reassigned each time the loop iterates over the 2D list(which would be the `data` parameter). Essentially, `img_rect` only refers to the list item you're iterating over. Outside of the loop it means nothing. I'm assuming you're going to want to update the position of the blocks using another method such as `world.update()` or something to that effect. You'd want to move the logic for determining what kind of block gets displayed out of your init method and into another separate method such as the one mentioned and then call that in your loop that runs the game. The init method of the class only runs once when you instantiate a new instance of the class.

As far as referring to the `img_rect` outside of the loop:
You create a tuple containing the `img` and `img_rect` called `tile` and add that tuple to another list called `tile_list`. If you want to access a specific tile's img_rect just say something like: `tile_list[i][1].x` i stands for the specific index number of the tile you wish to edit. You could do that in any method underneath the World class. Or again, you could even iterate over tile_list, there are endless possibilities.

Comment: Also, the other guys above were correct, in technical terms you don't call a variable. But I think I understood what you meant :) lmk if you have any questions

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for answering, do you think you could show me how you would write it as a tuple?

Comment: What is the end goal you're working towards with the World object? You say that you want to add another definition? What would that definition be doing? The question you're asking is one of scope, that variable is only available within that for loop. However, tile_list is accessible to the entire class. Also in your init function, you initialize tile_list as an empty array rather than setting it to a class parameter, I'm not sure if that was intentional or not. Double-check that.

Comment: The world class is supposed to be able to use world_data and check for 1s, or 2s (or if it is 0, nothing), within that data. You can see in the init definition that I use two if statements, if there is a 1 in world_data, then place a certain block that aligns with it. And yes it is an intentional list b/c I append that block that was just placed into that list and then we use 'screen.blit(tile[0], tile[1])' for as many items in that list. My end goal is to be able to change the blocks around so they slide left across the screen while the player is stationary and can jump over them.